# is there any way to define title page & abstract in tabular column & rest of contents in two column

Tags: titles, supertabular

i need to bring title & other contents as if in the image in two column document

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright}X}
\toprule
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1.86in]{image}} & \emph{xxxxxxxxxxx} \\
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    \emph{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\
    Some more sentence here. \tabularnewline
\midrule
{\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image}}} & \emph{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
    \emph{xxxxxxxxxx} \\
    Some more sentence here. \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright}X}
\toprule
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1.86in]{image}} & \emph{xxxxxxxxxxx} \\
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    \emph{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\
    Some more sentence here. \tabularnewline
\midrule
{\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image}}} & \emph{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
    \emph{xxxxxxxxxx} \\
    Some more sentence here. \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

Comment: i cant bring this to top of the page. it lies in center

Comment: Hmm, add that to the question, not here.

Comment: To bring it to top, you can add option `[h]`.

Comment: ok can i use vspace here to bring that to top

Comment: No. `\vspace` is not supposed to do so.

Comment: Anyway please expand your code snippet to a compilable one.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: there is no need to put `tabular` inside a `table` environment!

You can pass the table to `\twocolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{microtype} % recommended for twocolum

\usepackage{showframe} % to show the page boundaries
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{%
  \sffamily\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l >{\raggedright}X @{}}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\Large % tight frame and match the font in the top line
  \fbox{\includegraphics[height=1.86in,valign=t]{example-image-9x16}} &
  {\Large Title of this paper\\}
  A. Uthor\\[3ex]
  {\itshape University of Nowhere\\ Somewhere}\\[3ex]
  \texttt{a.uthor@nowhere.edu}
  \tabularnewline\tabularnewline &
  \textbf{Abstract:} This is the abstract, maybe long enough to break
  across lines, let's stop here because it seems sufficient.\\[2ex]
  \textbf{Keywords:} Abstract, tabularx
  \end{tabularx}\par\vspace{10ex}%
}]

\section{Introduction}

\kant

\end{document}
```

The packages `showframe` and `kantlipsum` are used just to show the page boundaries and to make some filler text.

[image]

Without frame:

[image]

A higher level version:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{microtype} % recommended for twocolum

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \twocolumn[{%
    \sffamily\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l >{\raggedright}X @{}}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\Large % tight frame and match the font in the top line
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=1.86in,valign=t]{\lalli@photo}} &
    {\Large\@title\\}
    \@author\\[3ex]
    {\itshape\lalli@address}\\[3ex]
    \texttt{\lalli@email}
    \tabularnewline\tabularnewline &
    \textbf{Abstract:} \lalli@abstract\\[2ex]
    \textbf{Keywords:} \lalli@keywords
    \end{tabularx}\par\vspace{10ex}%
  }]%
}
\newcommand{\photo}[1]{\gdef\lalli@photo{#1}}
\newcommand{\address}[1]{\gdef\lalli@address{#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\gdef\lalli@email{#1}}
\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{\long\gdef\lalli@abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\gdef\lalli@keywords{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Title of this paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\photo{example-image-9x16}
\address{University of Nowhere\\ Somewhere}
\email{a.uthor@nowhere.edu}
\abstract{This is the abstract, maybe long enough to break
  across lines, let's stop here because it seems sufficient.}
\keywords{Abstract, tabularx}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\kant

\end{document}
```